# "Does not name a type" compile error, right after the definition of the class template in Arduino

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors, arduino

I have compiled this code in Eclipse IDE with GCC and with having C++ standard / dialect equal to C++11 without any error.

```
template<typename TYPE>
class ToSerialHex
{
public:
  enum
  {
    DIGITS_COUNT = uint8_t(sizeof(TYPE)) * uint8_t(2)
  };

  uint8_t digits[DIGITS_COUNT];

  ToSerialHex(TYPE value)
  {
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < sizeof(TYPE); ++idx) {
      uint8_t temp = byteOf(value, sizeof(TYPE) - idx - 1U);
      digits[idx * 2] = temp / 16U;
      digits[(idx * 2)+ 1] = temp % 16U;
    }
  }
};

template<typename PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
size_t operator<<(PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE& printerObject, const ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> &hexObject)
{
  typedef ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> HEX_TYPE;
  size_t count = 0;
  for(size_t idx = 0; idx < HEX_TYPE::DIGITS_COUNT; ++idx) {
    count += printerObject.print(hexObject.digits[idx], HEX);
  }
  return count;
}
```

But when I compile it in Arduino IDE / envrionment which has the **same** C++ dialect, I get this error:

```
error: 'ToSerialHex' does not name a type
```

The whole program for Arduino is:

```
#include <Wire.h>

#include <ctype.h> 

constexpr uint32_t serialSpeed = 115200;

constexpr uint8_t EEPROM_sector = 83;
constexpr uint8_t System_sector = 87;

constexpr uint16_t maxbytesPerLine = 16;

constexpr uint16_t EEPROMbytes = 2048;
constexpr uint16_t I2Cpasswordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t RF0passwordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t RF1passwordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t RF2passwordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t DSFIDbytes = 1;
constexpr uint16_t AFIbytes = 1;
constexpr uint16_t UIDbytes = 8;
constexpr uint16_t Configurationbytes = 1;
constexpr uint16_t Lockbitbytes = 2;
constexpr uint16_t SSSbytes = 10;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(serialSpeed);  // start serial for output
}




//**********************************************************
typedef decltype(sizeof(1)) size_t;

template<typename TYPE>
uint8_t byteOf(TYPE value, size_t idx)
{
  value <<= ((sizeof(TYPE) - idx - size_t(1)) * 8);
  value >>= ((sizeof(TYPE) - size_t(1)) * 8);
  return uint8_t(value);
}

template<typename TYPE>
class ToSerialHex;

template<typename TYPE>
class ToSerialHex
{
public:
  enum
  {
    DIGITS_COUNT = uint8_t(sizeof(TYPE)) * uint8_t(2)
  };

  uint8_t digits[DIGITS_COUNT];

  ToSerialHex(TYPE value)
  {
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < sizeof(TYPE); ++idx) {
      uint8_t temp = byteOf(value, sizeof(TYPE) - idx - 1U);
      digits[idx * 2] = temp / 16U;
      digits[(idx * 2)+ 1] = temp % 16U;
    }
  }
};
template<typename PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
size_t operator<<(PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE& printerObject, const ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> &hexObject)
{
  typedef ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> HEX_TYPE;
  size_t count = 0;
  for(size_t idx = 0; idx < HEX_TYPE::DIGITS_COUNT; ++idx) {
    count += printerObject.print(hexObject.digits[idx], HEX);
  }
  return count;
}



template<uint16_t NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, uint16_t SPECIAL_COUNT>
struct Window{
  enum : uint16_t {
    normal_block_count = NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT,
    special_count = SPECIAL_COUNT,
  };
};


namespace helpers {
template<uint8_t DEVICE_ADDRESS, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_PER_LINE, char NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, uint16_t SPECIAL_COUNT, uint16_t ... OTHERS>
class Windows
{
  typedef Windows<DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, NORMAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, OTHERS ...> next;
public:
  static void go() {
    if(NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT) {
      if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }

      for(uint16_t lineCounter = NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT; lineCounter--;) {
        Wire.requestFrom(int(DEVICE_ADDRESS), int(NORMAL_PER_LINE), int(true));
  
        char read[NORMAL_PER_LINE] = {};
        {
          uint8_t idx = 0;
          while (Wire.available()) {
            read[idx++] = Wire.read();
          }
        }
  
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
          Serial.print(", ");
        }
  
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
            Serial.print(read[idx]);
          } else {
            Serial.print(".");
          }
        }
  
        Serial.println("");
        delay(10);
      }

      if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }
    }

    if (SPECIAL_COUNT) {
      if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }

      for(uint16_t lineCounter = SPECIAL_COUNT / MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; lineCounter--;) {
        Wire.requestFrom(int(DEVICE_ADDRESS), int(MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE), int(true));

        char read[MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
        {
          uint8_t idx = 0;
          while (Wire.available()) {
            read[idx++] = Wire.read();
          }
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
          Serial.print(", ");
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
            Serial.print(read[idx]);
          } else {
            Serial.print(".");
          }
        }

        Serial.println("");
        delay(10);
      }

      if(SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE) {
        Wire.requestFrom(int(DEVICE_ADDRESS), int(SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE), int(true));

        char read[SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
        {
          uint8_t idx = 0;
          while (Wire.available()) {
            read[idx++] = Wire.read();
          }
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
          Serial.print(", ");
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
            Serial.print(read[idx]);
          } else {
            Serial.print(".");
          }
        }

        Serial.println("");
        delay(10);
      }

      if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }
    }
    return next::go();
  }

public:
  Windows(uint16_t offset = 0) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    Wire.write(offset / 256);
    Wire.write(offset % 256);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    go();
  }
};

template<uint8_t DEVICE_ADDRESS, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_PER_LINE, char NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, uint16_t SPECIAL_COUNT>
class Windows<DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, NORMAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, SPECIAL_COUNT>
{
public:
  static void go() {
    if(NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT) {
      if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }

      if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }
    }
    for(uint16_t lineCounter = NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT; lineCounter--;) {
      Wire.requestFrom(int(DEVICE_ADDRESS), int(NORMAL_PER_LINE), int(true));

      char read[NORMAL_PER_LINE] = {};
      {
        uint8_t idx = 0;
        while (Wire.available()) {
          read[idx++] = Wire.read();
        }
      }

      for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
        Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
        Serial.print(", ");
      }

      for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
        if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
          Serial.print(read[idx]);
        } else {
          Serial.print(".");
        }
      }

      Serial.println("");
      delay(10);
    }

    if (SPECIAL_COUNT) {
      if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }

      for(uint16_t lineCounter = SPECIAL_COUNT / MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; lineCounter--;) {
        Wire.requestFrom(int(DEVICE_ADDRESS), int(MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE), int(true));

        char read[MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
        {
          uint8_t idx = 0;
          while (Wire.available()) {
            read[idx++] = Wire.read();
          }
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
          Serial.print(", ");
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
            Serial.print(read[idx]);
          } else {
            Serial.print(".");
          }
        }

        Serial.println("");
        delay(10);
      }

      if(SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE) {
        Wire.requestFrom(int(DEVICE_ADDRESS), int(SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE), int(true));

        char read[SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
        {
          uint8_t idx = 0;
          while (Wire.available()) {
            read[idx++] = Wire.read();
          }
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
          Serial.print(", ");
        }

        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
            Serial.print(read[idx]);
          } else {
            Serial.print(".");
          }
        }

        Serial.println("");
        delay(10);
      }

      if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
        for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
          Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
        }
        Serial.println("");
      }
    }
  }

public:
  Windows(uint16_t offset = 0) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    Wire.write(offset / 256);
    Wire.write(offset % 256);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    go();
  }
};

} // namespace helpers

template<uint8_t DEVICE_ADDRESS, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE = 3, uint16_t NORMAL_PER_LINE = 5, char NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER = '[', char SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER = '(', char NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER = ']', char SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER = ')'>
struct Dump {
  template<uint16_t ... values>
  class Windows:
      public helpers::Windows<DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, NORMAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER , SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE * NORMAL_PER_LINE, values ...>
      {};
};
//*********************************************************

bool done = false;

typedef Dump<EEPROM_sector> Dump_type;
typedef Dump_type::Windows<0, 1,   8, 40,   34, 899,   25, 262,   25,0,   0, 1,   0, 131   ,51,0> Windows_type;

void loop() {
  if(not done) {
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");

    Windows_type();
        
    done = true;
  }

  delay(2000);
}
```

The error happens right after the end of the definition(end of the `ToSerialHex` class scope).

The whole error is:

```
I2C_eeprom_read_3:77:120: error: 'ToSerialHex' does not name a type
   77 | };
      |                                                                                                                        ^          
I2C_eeprom_read_3:77:131: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
   77 | };
      |                                                                                                                                   ^
exit status 1
'ToSerialHex' does not name a type
```

And in order to mimic Arduino environment I used this program in eclipse:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "ctype.h"

class serial{
public:
    serial(...){}
    int print(...){return 0;}
    int println(...){return 0;}
} Serial;

static constexpr int HEX = 0;

class wire{
public:
    wire(...){}
    void beginTransmission(...){}
    void endTransmission(...){}
    void write(...){}
    int read(...){return 0;}
    void requestFrom(...){}
    bool available(...){ return true;}
} Wire;

void delay(...){}

typedef decltype(sizeof(1)) size_t;

template<typename TYPE>
uint8_t byteOf(TYPE value, size_t idx)
{
    value <<= ((sizeof(TYPE) - idx - size_t(1)) * 8);
    value >>= ((sizeof(TYPE) - size_t(1)) * 8);
    return uint8_t(value);
}

template<typename TYPE>
class ToSerialHex
{
public:
    enum : size_t
    {
        DIGITS_COUNT = uint8_t(sizeof(TYPE)) * uint8_t(2)
    };

    uint8_t digits[DIGITS_COUNT];

    ToSerialHex(TYPE value)
    {
        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < sizeof(TYPE); ++idx) {
            uint8_t temp = byteOf(value, sizeof(TYPE) - idx - 1U);
            digits[idx * 2] = temp / 16U;
            digits[(idx * 2)+ 1] = temp % 16U;
        }
    }
};

template<typename PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
size_t operator<<(PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE& printerObject, const ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> &hexObject)
{
    typedef ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> HEX_TYPE;
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < HEX_TYPE::DIGITS_COUNT; ++idx) {
        count += printerObject.print(hexObject.digits[idx], HEX);
    }
    return count;
}



template<uint16_t NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, uint16_t SPECIAL_COUNT>
struct Window{
    enum : uint16_t {
        normal_block_count = NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT,
        special_count = SPECIAL_COUNT,
    };
};


namespace helpers {
template<uint8_t DEVICE_ADDRESS, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_PER_LINE, char NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, uint16_t SPECIAL_COUNT, uint16_t ... OTHERS>
class Windows
{
    typedef Windows<DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, NORMAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, OTHERS ...> next;
public:
    static void go() {
        if(NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT) {
            if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }

            if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }
        }
        for(uint16_t lineCounter = NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT; lineCounter--;) {
            Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, NORMAL_PER_LINE, true);

            char read[NORMAL_PER_LINE] = {};
            {
                uint8_t idx = 0;
                while (Wire.available()) {
                    read[idx++] = Wire.read();
                }
            }

            for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
                Serial.print(", ");
            }

            for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
                    Serial.print(read[idx]);
                } else {
                    Serial.print(".");
                }
            }

            Serial.println("");
            delay(10);
        }

        if (SPECIAL_COUNT) {
            if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }

            for(uint16_t lineCounter = SPECIAL_COUNT / MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; lineCounter--;) {
                Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, true);

                char read[MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
                {
                    uint8_t idx = 0;
                    while (Wire.available()) {
                        read[idx++] = Wire.read();
                    }
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
                    Serial.print(", ");
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
                        Serial.print(read[idx]);
                    } else {
                        Serial.print(".");
                    }
                }

                Serial.println("");
                delay(10);
            }

            if(SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE) {
                Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, true);

                char read[SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
                {
                    uint8_t idx = 0;
                    while (Wire.available()) {
                        read[idx++] = Wire.read();
                    }
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
                    Serial.print(", ");
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
                        Serial.print(read[idx]);
                    } else {
                        Serial.print(".");
                    }
                }

                Serial.println("");
                delay(10);
            }

            if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }
        }
        return next::go();
    }

public:
    Windows(uint16_t offset = 0) {
        Wire.beginTransmission(DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        Wire.write(offset / 256);
        Wire.write(offset % 256);
        Wire.endTransmission();
        go();
    }
};

template<uint8_t DEVICE_ADDRESS, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_PER_LINE, char NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, char NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, char SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, uint16_t NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, uint16_t SPECIAL_COUNT>
class Windows<DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, NORMAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT, SPECIAL_COUNT>
{
public:
    static void go() {
        if(NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT) {
            if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }

            if(isprint(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 *NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }
        }
        for(uint16_t lineCounter = NORMAL_BLOCK_COUNT; lineCounter--;) {
            Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, NORMAL_PER_LINE, true);

            char read[NORMAL_PER_LINE] = {};
            {
                uint8_t idx = 0;
                while (Wire.available()) {
                    read[idx++] = Wire.read();
                }
            }

            for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
                Serial.print(", ");
            }

            for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < NORMAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
                    Serial.print(read[idx]);
                } else {
                    Serial.print(".");
                }
            }

            Serial.println("");
            delay(10);
        }

        if (SPECIAL_COUNT) {
            if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }

            for(uint16_t lineCounter = SPECIAL_COUNT / MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; lineCounter--;) {
                Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, true);

                char read[MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
                {
                    uint8_t idx = 0;
                    while (Wire.available()) {
                        read[idx++] = Wire.read();
                    }
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
                    Serial.print(", ");
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
                        Serial.print(read[idx]);
                    } else {
                        Serial.print(".");
                    }
                }

                Serial.println("");
                delay(10);
            }

            if(SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE) {
                Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE, true);

                char read[SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE] = {};
                {
                    uint8_t idx = 0;
                    while (Wire.available()) {
                        read[idx++] = Wire.read();
                    }
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial << ToSerialHex<uint8_t>(read[idx]);
                    Serial.print(", ");
                }

                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < SPECIAL_COUNT % MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    if (isalnum(read[idx])) {
                        Serial.print(read[idx]);
                    } else {
                        Serial.print(".");
                    }
                }

                Serial.println("");
                delay(10);
            }

            if(isprint(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER)) {
                for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 4 * MAX_SPECIAL_PER_LINE; ++idx) {
                    Serial.print(SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER);
                }
                Serial.println("");
            }
        }
    }

public:
    Windows(uint16_t offset = 0) {
        Wire.beginTransmission(DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        Wire.write(offset / 256);
        Wire.write(offset % 256);
        Wire.endTransmission();
        go();
    }
};

} // namespace helpers

template<uint8_t DEVICE_ADDRESS, uint16_t MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE = 3, uint16_t NORMAL_PER_LINE = 5, char NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER = '[', char SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER = '(', char NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER = ']', char SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER = ')'>
struct Dump {
    template<uint16_t ... values>
    class Windows:
            public helpers::Windows<DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE, NORMAL_PER_LINE, NORMAL_BLOCK_HEADER , SPECIAL_BLOCK_HEADER, NORMAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, SPECIAL_BLOCK_FOOTER, MAX_SPECIAL_BLOCKS_PER_LINE * NORMAL_PER_LINE, values ...>
            {};
};


constexpr uint8_t EEPROM_sector = 83;
typedef Dump<EEPROM_sector> Dump_type;
typedef Dump_type::Windows<0, 1,   8, 40,   34, 899,   25, 262,   25,0,   0, 1,   0, 131   ,51,0> Windows_type;





int main() {
    Windows_type();
    std::cout << "THE END" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is right: `ToSerialHex` does not name a type. It names a **template**, which is a pattern for creating types. That's pretty much all anyone can say, since the question doesn't quote the actual error message or indicate where in this (far too large) mass of code the error occurred.

Comment: @PeteBecker Compiler error message is saying that error happened right after the template class definition! I will update my question

Comment: Arduino does some weird preprocessing of code, adding forward-declarations of functions at the top. I suppose that could be messing with your code. (I have no experience with Arduino though, so I don't know how this is supposed to be handled.)

Comment: @PeteBecker I also believe, "The compiler is always right"  too! But here a same compiler is giving error in one IDE, while it does not do it in another IDE!

Comment: @newbie -- I didn't say the compiler is always right. I said the compiler is right.

Comment: @JasonLiam in Arduino environment ,```HEX``` is defined as a constant some where (which I do not know where!). Other codes are fine using ```HEX``` in Arduino. In order to have it defined in eclipse I used ```static constexpr int HEX = 0;```

Comment: you can check the ino processed to cpp in the temporary build folder. you will see the path in console if you enable verbose output for build

Comment: @Juraj how can I do that?

Comment: you can enable verbose output in Preferences in IDE

Comment: Also understand that when a compiler is marked as supporting a specific C++ version, it does not necessarily means it supports ALL of that version. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/11

Comment: @MikelF  Thanks for the reminder, BUT, I am already aware of that fact! Also both of the GCC which was used (In Arduino case and Eclipse case) has a version high enough to support almost ALL of  C++11 !

Comment: Does the DIGITS_COUNT enum need to be defined as static? As it currently stands, it doesn't necessarily exist if not instantiated.

Comment: @MikelF I do not understand what you mean by "static". It is an ```enum``` not a member variable! But you are correct if you mean, In this code, It does not need to exist at all. Right now I can not remember beside the size of the array for the operator overloading, what other extra purpose I had in mind for ```DIGITS_COUNT```.

Comment: And that is why I need caffeine before I post. My hunch is that the error is thrown because of something to do with the constructor.

Comment: @MikelF You might be right and that was my first guess to, and I want to try that (the constructor) in other formats too. But right now MY hunch is: The whole Arduino shenanigans was designed by people who don't understand / know C++, for people who also don't understand / know C++. The second term also goes for STM32 HAL library

Comment: @MikelF Once, I met a person who was friend with Arduino project developers, them selves. And after he told me that fact (being friend with the developers), the only thing I asked him was to tell them to STOP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the "piece of art" preprocessing in the Arduino (as mentioned by @user17732522)
, that causes those errors. This is how it looks like after preprocessing (relevant lines only):

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#line 1 "C:\\Users\\kiiv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_530601\\sketch_sep24a.ino"
#include <Wire.h>

#include <ctype.h> 

constexpr uint32_t serialSpeed = 115200;

constexpr uint8_t EEPROM_sector = 83;
constexpr uint8_t System_sector = 87;

constexpr uint16_t maxbytesPerLine = 16;

constexpr uint16_t EEPROMbytes = 2048;
constexpr uint16_t I2Cpasswordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t RF0passwordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t RF1passwordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t RF2passwordbytes = 4;
constexpr uint16_t DSFIDbytes = 1;
constexpr uint16_t AFIbytes = 1;
constexpr uint16_t UIDbytes = 8;
constexpr uint16_t Configurationbytes = 1;
constexpr uint16_t Lockbitbytes = 2;
constexpr uint16_t SSSbytes = 10;

#line 24 "C:\\Users\\kiiv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_530601\\sketch_sep24a.ino"
void setup();
#line 34 "C:\\Users\\kiiv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_530601\\sketch_sep24a.ino"
template<typename TYPE>uint8_t byteOf(TYPE value, size_t idx);
#line 65 "C:\\Users\\kiiv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_530601\\sketch_sep24a.ino"
template<typename PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>size_t operator<<(PRINTER_OBJECT_TYPE& printerObject, const ToSerialHex<VALUE_TYPE> &hexObject);
#line 24 "C:\\Users\\kiiv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_530601\\sketch_sep24a.ino"
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(serialSpeed);  // start serial for output
}
```

Now you can see why it reports error on line 65 (full code reported it on 65 instead of yours 67) and also why you can compile it on anything that doesn't do crappy preprocessing for the beginners, that can't handle forward declarations for functions :)

BTW: if you move: `template<typename TYPE> class ToSerialHex;` to the line 22, it'll work again

BTW2: the Arduino IDE allows to add another files into the "sketch" directory, so you can just remove everything from the .ino file and create .cpp file with everything in it (including setup and loop) - it just needs  #include <Arduino.h>  if you don't have it already. Like this you'll completely avoid this .ino prepreprocessor and therefore all magicall bugs it causes

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answered the question, and I also learned something about Arduino (or so called, Dirty Lazy tool for embedded programing for those who don't know C++, by those who also don't know C++). How ever I am not sure what were you referring to by "piece of art". I would never use Arduino if it is up to me and I am not explicitly asked to use it.

Comment: I didn't want to use c**p word, thats why "art" :D Basically it never works with anything but basic C++ :) And the down vote isn't mine, so no idea.